# Estimate for integral of $f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{z(z^2+1)^2}$ on upper semi circle with center 0 and radius $R$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{z(z^2+1)^2}$ and the curve $C_R$ is given by $\displaystyle C_R=\{z\in\mathbb C~:~|z|=R>1,~Im(z)>0\}$.

Prove the inequality $$\left|\int_{C_R}f(z)dz\right|\leq \frac{\pi}{(R^2-1)^2}$$

Here I tried with ML inequality. We can see $|e^{iz}|=e^{-Im(z)}\in(e^{-R},1)$ on $C_R$. But I couldn't make $$\frac{1}{|z^2+1|^2}\leq \frac{1}{(R^2-1)^2}$$ eventhough $|z-i|\geq R-1$ on $C_R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the triangle inequality: $|z^2+1|+|-1|\ge|z^2|$, so $|z^2+1|\ge R^2-1$.
As long as $R>1$, then $1/|z^2+1|^2\ge1/(R^2-1)^2$.